# Installing python packages in linux which doesn't have network connection using windows

Tags: python, package, requirements.txt

pip install packagename.whl
is not working in linux
Can you please suggest me something for installation of python packages in linux with no internet connection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you have some device that has a network connection,
so probably download the libraries onto some kind of medium, sd card, usb drive, and then build them on the board using the build instructions, usually in the readme or something.
You will have to be careful, since you wont be using pip, to check the version of python you have and download the corresponding/compatible version of the library.